# Is StackOverflow using DoubleVerify / Evidon?

Tags: support, advertising

I noticed a suspicious ad every now and then in my SO sidebar (in the usual place):

[image]

Is this by design, or do I have a rogue browser extension?

Comment: Which one is the suspicious one?

Comment: Well, I can reproduce that ad showing up, but I don't know that it's necessarily by design.

Comment: @random: The one that's cut off and with a large white gap.

Comment: Are you using a browser? Do you have extensions? What are these extensions? What is the browser you're using?

Comment: @random: Firefox, with a large number of extensions.  It's easier to ask here than to go through all of those extensions.  I looked through the source & HTTP requests, and I couldn't easily see how it got to `http://rtbcdn.doubleverify.com/bsredirect5.js?...`

Comment: For the record, I'm running IE 10 without any extensions, and I still see that ad.