# Banner ads should not be shown on the right-hand ad slot

Tags: support, advertising

The banner ads are in the wrong format for the right-hand ad slot:

[image: Banner ad looks all wrong in the right-hand ad slot]

These kinds of ads are not useful (because most of it is cropped) and should be excluded from being shown in that spot.

Comment: Seems to be slightly related to this question: [Is StackOverflow using DoubleVerify / Evidon?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195045/is-stackoverflow-using-doubleverify-evidon)

Comment: @chuex Seems to be highly related to that question, except that I run my Firefox with very few addons.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: In other words, the answer to my question is "Yes".

Comment: Looks like it's disabled now, I have reloaded 20 times and got only Careers ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon noticing the issue I reached out to the client, as it appears to be caused by an update on their end. That particular placement is now turned off until I receive word that it is fixed.

I'll post any relevant updates here.

Thank you for keeping an eye out!

---

All fixed!