# "Only secure content is displayed" appears on some pages in IE11

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

Sometimes when I navigate to a page in Stack Overflow, Internet Explorer will warn that "Only secure content is displayed." The only HTTPS requests logged in Developer Tools are to

- www.gravatar.com (image/png)
- a248.e.akamai.net (image/jpeg)
- view.atdmt.com (text/html, frame navigate)

For example, the warning appeared when the ad below was shown. The ad is located within an `<iframe src="https://view.atdmt.com/...">` within an `<iframe id="ados_frame_adzerk...">` within a `<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow adzerk-vote" id="adzerk...">`.

> [image]

Comment: Ah, I remember there being something weird about that Windows Azure ad. It's been brought up before but I don't think it was about secure connections. I'm not very good at searching on my phone but "windows azure ad" will probably turn something up that's useful. Best bet - Microsoft probably includes non-secure content in their ads. Stack Exchange would have to get them to fix it.

Comment: @animuson probably [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196102/malicious-ads-or-just-simple-error-messages).

Comment: I'm going to start paying more attention and see if it's solely this ad that's causing the warning to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of us starting to implement SSL site wide... Not all content is served up securely yet, but we're working on it. In case of the ad, as @animuson pointed out, it's serving up some non-secure content, and we've reached out to them to fix that.